# Prevent redirect to /Account/Login in asp.net core 2.2

Tags: asp.net-core-2.2

I am trying to prevent the app to redirect to `/Account/Login` in asp.net core 2.2 when the user isn't logged in.

Even though i write `LoginPath = new PathString("/api/contests");` any unauthorized requests are still redirected to `/Account/Login`

This is my Startup.cs:

```cs
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using AutoMapper;
using Contest.Models;
using Contest.Tokens;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger;

namespace Contest
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

            services.AddAutoMapper();

            // In production, the React files will be served from this directory
            services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
            {
                configuration.RootPath = "clientapp/build";
            });

            // ===== Add our DbContext ========
            string connection = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DBLocalConnection");
            string migrationAssemblyName = typeof(Startup).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetName().Name;
            services.AddDbContext<ContestContext>(options =>
                    options.UseSqlServer(connection,
                    sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(migrationAssemblyName)));

            // ===== Add Identity ========
            services.AddIdentity<User, IdentityRole>(o =>
            {
                o.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
                o.Tokens.EmailConfirmationTokenProvider = "EMAILCONF";
                // I want to be able to resend an `Email` confirmation email
                // o.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true; 
            }).AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ContestContext>()
                .AddTokenProvider<EmailConfirmationTokenProvider<User>>("EMAILCONF")
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

            services.Configure<DataProtectionTokenProviderOptions>(o =>
                o.TokenLifespan = TimeSpan.FromHours(3)
            );

            services.Configure<EmailConfirmationTokenProviderOptions>(o =>
                o.TokenLifespan = TimeSpan.FromDays(2)
            );

            // ===== Add Authentication ========

            services.AddAuthentication(o => o.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddCookie(options =>
                {
                    options.Cookie.Name = "auth_cookie";
                    options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
                    options.LoginPath = new PathString("/api/contests");
                    options.AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/api/contests");
                    options.Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents
                    {
                        OnRedirectToLogin = context =>
                        {
                            context.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized;
                            return Task.CompletedTask;
                        },
                    };
                });

            // ===== Add Authorization ========

            services.AddAuthorization(o =>
            {

            });

            services.AddCors();

            // ===== Add MVC ========
            services.AddMvc(config =>
            {
                var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                                    .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                                    .Build();
                config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
            })
                .AddJsonOptions(options => options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore)
                .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);

            // ===== Add Swagger ========
            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info
                {
                    Title = "Core API",
                    Description = "Documentation",
                });

                var xmlPath = $"{System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory}Contest.xml";
                c.IncludeXmlComments(xmlPath);
            });

        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseSpaStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
            {

            });

            app.UseCors(policy =>
            {
                policy.AllowAnyHeader();
                policy.AllowAnyMethod();
                policy.AllowAnyOrigin();
                policy.AllowCredentials();
            });

            app.UseAuthentication();

            app.UseMvc();

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseSwagger();
                app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
                {
                    c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Core API");
                });
            }

            app.UseSpa(spa =>
            {
                spa.Options.SourcePath = "clientapp";

                if (env.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    // spa.UseReactDevelopmentServer(npmScript: "start");
                    spa.UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer("http://localhost:3000");
                }
            });

        }

    }
}
```

I managed to bypass this by creating a controller to handle this route:

```cs
[Route("/")]
[ApiController]
public class UnauthorizedController : ControllerBase
{
    public UnauthorizedController()
    {

    }

    [HttpGet("/Account/Login")]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public IActionResult Login()
    {
        HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized;
        return new ObjectResult(new
        {
            StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized,
            Message = "Unauthorized",
        });
    }

}
```

What is wrong with my setup?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The behaviour you experience is linked to the fact that you use ASP.NET Identity.
When you call `services.AddIdentity`, behind the scenes a cookie-based authentication scheme is registered and set as the default challenge scheme, as you can see in the code [here on GitHub](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/5a64688d8e192cacffda9440e8725c1ed41a30cf/src/Identity/src/Identity/IdentityServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L45-L76).

Even though you registered a cookie authentication scheme yourself and set it as the default scheme, the specific default schemes — like `AuthenticateScheme`, `ChallengeScheme`, `SignInScheme`, etc... — take precendence. `DefaultScheme` is used by the authentication system only when the specific one is not set.

To answer your question, you could apply the configuration settings to the ASP.NET Identity cookie options by using the helper method [`services.ConfigureApplicationCookie`](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/5a64688d8e192cacffda9440e8725c1ed41a30cf/src/Identity/src/Identity/IdentityServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L109-L110), like so:

```cs
// ===== Add Identity ========
services.AddIdentity<User, IdentityRole>(o =>
{
    o.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
    o.Tokens.EmailConfirmationTokenProvider = "EMAILCONF";
    // I want to be able to resend an `Email` confirmation email
    // o.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true; 
}).AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ContestContext>()
    .AddTokenProvider<EmailConfirmationTokenProvider<User>>("EMAILCONF")
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

services.Configure<DataProtectionTokenProviderOptions>(o =>
    o.TokenLifespan = TimeSpan.FromHours(3)
);

services.Configure<EmailConfirmationTokenProviderOptions>(o =>
    o.TokenLifespan = TimeSpan.FromDays(2)
);

// ===== Configure Identity =======
service.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    options.Cookie.Name = "auth_cookie";
    options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
    options.LoginPath = new PathString("/api/contests");
    options.AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/api/contests");

    // Not creating a new object since ASP.NET Identity has created
    // one already and hooked to the OnValidatePrincipal event.
    // See https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/5a64688d8e192cacffda9440e8725c1ed41a30cf/src/Identity/src/Identity/IdentityServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L56
    options.Events.OnRedirectToLogin = context =>
    {
        context.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized;
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    };
});
```

It also means that you can safely remove the part where you add a cookie-based authentication scheme since this is taken care of by ASP.NET Identity itself.

Comment: What if you instead wanted to be sure it all got redirected to an https coupling? See, I found my site redirecting to http, even though my entry was to an https page.

Answer (score 13):

If you are **not** using ASP.NET **Identity**, you can follow the same pattern that [kuldeep chopra](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12199617) mentioned in another answer, but instead inside the `AddCookie` method:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
 services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddCookie((o) =>
    {
      o.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
      o.LoginPath = string.Empty;
      o.AccessDeniedPath = string.Empty;
      o.Events.OnRedirectToLogin = context =>
      {
        context.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized;
        return Task.CompletedTask;
      };
    });
}
```

It is not enough to just set the paths to empty/null.

Answer (score 5):

```
 services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options => {
            options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Account/Login";
            options.LoginPath = "/Account/Denied";
            options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
            options.Events.OnRedirectToLogin = context => {
                context.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized;
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            };
        });
```

Comment: options.Events.OnRedirectToLogin = context => {
                context.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized;
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            };  this event stop you to redirect the page to log when http status code is 401 unathorized

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue and made a workaround , I just create a controller "Account" and write the Redirection inside it:

```
    public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Login()
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Login", "Home");
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is just a band aid for the actual problem, additionally it adds an unnecessary redirect.

Answer (score -1):

The issue was that I had this code at the bottom of the scope!

```
options.Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents
                {
                    OnSigningIn = async context =>
                    {
                        context.Options.Cookie.Domain = context.HttpContext.Request.Host.Host;
                    }
                };
```

Once I moved it to the top, it started work!

So what code did I have?

```
services
            .AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddScheme<CerveraProxyAuthenticationOptions, CerveraProxyAuthenticationSchemeHandler>(ProxyAuthentication.AuthenticationScheme, options => { })
            .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
            {
                options.Events.OnRedirectToLogin = (o) =>
                {
                    o.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                };
                options.Events.OnRedirectToAccessDenied = (o) =>
                {
                    o.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Forbidden;
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                };
                if (cookieSettings.LocalizationCookieExpiration.TryConvertToTimeSpan(out TimeSpan expiration))
                {
                    options.ExpireTimeSpan = expiration;
                    options.Cookie.MaxAge = expiration;
                }

                options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = cookieSettings.SecureCookies
                    ? CookieSecurePolicy.Always
                    : CookieSecurePolicy.SameAsRequest;
                options.Cookie.Path = "/";
                options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
                options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
                SameSiteMode sameSiteMode = Enum.Parse<SameSiteMode>(cookieSettings.SameSite);
                options.Cookie.SameSite = sameSiteMode;
                options.Cookie.Name = cookieSettings.AuthenticationCookieName;
                options.Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents
                {
                    OnSigningIn = async context =>
                    {
                        context.Options.Cookie.Domain = context.HttpContext.Request.Host.Host;
                    }
                };
            });
```

Comment: Of course it worked when moving it to the top. When it was at the bottom, all the `options.Events` settings you did at the top were killed when you assigned a new instance to `options.Events`.