# Authorize attribute tag not working ASP web API

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-authorization

I am expecting a 401 when the user isn't logged in.
However the authorization tag isn't working.
I authenticate a user using AzureAd through Office 365 accounts.
The login controller is allowed to be anonymous and the user controller should be authorized.

This is my startup where I add authentication.

```
services.AddAuthorization(options => {                         
                options.DefaultPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder().RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build();
            });
```

The login controller is allowed to be anonymous and the user controller should be authorized.

```
[Authorize]
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult<User> Get() {
            var user = new User();
            user.Name = this.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name.ToString();
            return this.Ok(user);
        }

services.AddAuthorization(options => {
            options.DefaultPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder().RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build();
        });
```

Comment: Please post you code as actual text - never as images.

Comment: @Xerillio changed that now

Comment: Thanks. So what actually happens instead of getting a 401? And what's the value of `HttpContext.User.Identity.Name`?

Comment: When testing in postman to the url https://localhost:5001/api/User it returns a status 302

Comment: To which it should return 401 unauthorized because postman isn't logged in.

Comment: I think [this may answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53926368/3034273) your question then

Comment: Not quite what I'm looking for - believe there is a method to add the [Authorize] attribute above the methods I want to restrict just not sure how to set that up.

Comment: The `Authorize` attribute seems to work just fine. HTTP status `302` is a redirect to the login page because you aren't authenticated. I believe [at the moment](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/9039) this is the default behaviour when using cookie authentication. To fix that you should follow the answer I linked to. If that doesn't work, then please update your question showing your attempt.