# Prevent redirect to /Account/Login in asp.net Core 5 Razor pages

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-5, asp.net-core-5.0

I have an ASP.NET Core 5 Web App Razor Pages (not MVC) project where an user can login via the /Index page.
But when I use an url to a page without logging in (e.g. http://localhost:57257/Test2) I get a 404 error and get redirected to: http://localhost:57257/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2FTest2

I have tried the answers and comments from this question: [Prevent redirect to /Account/Login in asp.net core 2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53925609/prevent-redirect-to-account-login-in-asp-net-core-2-2)
but none of them worked. I keep getting redirected Account/Login if the user is not logged in.

The funny part is that if I use an url with a non-existing page (e.g. http://localhost:57257/Test2222), all goes well and the page is redirected to /Index

Basically, I do not want to see a redirect to /Account/Login ever, the website must always redirect to / or /Index,
but im running out of options to try. Anyone any idea on how I can prevent this?

**Startup.cs**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory;
using System.Data.Common;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System;

namespace WordWeb
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddRazorPages(options =>
            {
                options.Conventions.AuthorizeFolder("/");
                options.Conventions.AllowAnonymousToPage("/Index");
                options.Conventions.AllowAnonymousToPage("/Aanmelden");
                options.Conventions.AllowAnonymousToPage("/Help");
                options.Conventions.AllowAnonymousToPage("/Error");
            });

            services.AddSession(options =>
            {
                options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(int.Parse(Configuration["Website:SessionTimeout"]));
                options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
                options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
            });

            services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
            services.AddAntiforgery(o => o.HeaderName = "XSRF-TOKEN");

            services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddCookie();
            services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
            {
                options.LoginPath = "/Index";
                options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Index";
                //options.AccessDeniedPath = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.PathString("/Index");

                options.Events.OnRedirectToLogin = context =>
                {
                    context.Response.StatusCode = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized;
                    return System.Threading.Tasks.Task.CompletedTask;
                };
            });

            services.AddControllersWithViews().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation(); 
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, IMemoryCache cache)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment() || Configuration["ErrorHandling:ShowErrorDetails"] == "1")
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseSession();

            DbProviderFactories.RegisterFactory("System.Data.SqlClient", SqlClientFactory.Instance); 

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapRazorPages(); 
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this for `services.AddAuthentication`

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })
    .AddCookie(options =>
    {
        options.Cookie.Path = "/";
        options.LoginPath = "/Index";
        options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Index";
    });
```

Comment: doesnt work for me, just get the "too many redirect" error